# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"s21101180756377t}?S<78O#!R1GdO)te19936004699339'

Tags: python

I'm getting ValueError while solving below question from code wars

"
Your job is to write a function which increments a string, to create a new string.

If the string already ends with a number, the number should be incremented by 1.
If the string does not end with a number. the number 1 should be appended to the new string.
Examples:

foo -> foo1

foobar23 -> foobar24

foo0042 -> foo0043

foo9 -> foo10

foo099 -> foo100

Attention: If the number has leading zeros the amount of digits should be considered.
"

Below image is my code. I'm also having trouble with wiring code on this website so I'm attaching an image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp2oo.png)

And below is the Error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwgIS.png)

---

```
def increment_string(strng):
    int('aasdd')
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    n,k,s = 0, 0, 0
    #string
    while n < len(strng) and strng[n] in ascii_lowercase:
        n += 1
    if n >= len(strng):
        return strng+str(1)
    else:
        k = len(strng[n:])
        S = int(''.join(strng[n:1]))+1
        return strng[:n] + str(s).zfill(k)
```

Traceback

```
STDERR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in < module>
    Test.assert_equals (increment_string(x), sklasdfjioweu2 (x))
  File "/home/codewarrior/so lution.py", line 14, in increment_string
    s = int(''.join(strng[n:]))+1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5y330U_H{C2w^745214B5X tMt 124378204825mT%0Zkt25419007092 1'
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: You should copy and paste your code into your question. Then select the code and format at as code by entering `ctrl-K.`. Error messages should also be copied and pasted into your question and are best formatted by preceding each line with a `>` character. See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: What would you like help with? Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: I OCR'd your images and added to your question - please validate.

Answer (score 0):

The end of the Traceback shows the string that cannot be converted to an `int`. That is a very long string and it includes characters that are not digits. The Traceback shows the line causing the error (`s=int(''.join(...)`.  I'd say that you have your logic wrong somewhere and `n` is not what it should be.  Given that your task is to *look at* the end of the string and *change* it based on what you find at the end you should start looking at the end.

```
>>> s = string.ascii_lowercase
>>> n = -1
>>> for c in s[::-1]:
...     print(n,c, end='\t')
...     n -= 1

-1 z    -2 y    -3 x    -4 w    -5 v    -6 u    -7 t    -8 s    -9 r    -10 q   -11 p   -12 o   -13 n   -14 m   -15 l   -16 k   -17 j   -18 i   -19 h   -20 g   -21 f   -22 e   -23 d   -24 c   -25 b   -26 a
```

`s[::-1]` is a common way to reverse a sequence.  Using a negative value in a slice selects items counting from the end of the sequence.

```
>>> s[-4]
'w'
```

In the loop you probably want to stop iterating when it finds a character that is not a digit.
.

```
>>> n = 0
>>> for c in s[::-1]:
...     if c in string.ascii_letters:
...         break
...     n -= 1
...     print(n,c, end='\t')

-1 3    -2 2    -3 1    
>>> n
-3
>>> s[n:]
'123'
>>>
```

[`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) might also be helpful.

If you prefer a while loop:

```
>>> n = -1
>>> while s[n].isdigit():
...     n -= 1
```

This would require an adjustment to `n` before using it.

```
>>> n
-4
>>> s[n:]
'z123'
>>> s[n+1:]
'123'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# your code goes here

def increment_string(string):
    if len(string)==0:
        return '1'
    index = 0
    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        if not char.isdigit():
            index = idx
    charc, digit = string[:index+1], string[index+1:]
    digit = int(digit) if len(digit)!=0 else 0
    inte = digit + 1

    return charc + str(inte)


check = ['aa','','aedq123','aq1eeee123','aqs0']

for i in check :
    print('{}  -> {}'.format(i,increment_string(i)))
```

output

```
aa  -> aa1
  -> 1
aedq123  -> aedq124
aq1eeee123  -> aq1eeee124
aqs0  -> aqs1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to be just the answer to your question, which is that the string your are trying to convert is not the string representation of an `int`. You should put in some print statements to see what the original string being passed to your function was and one right before your statement:

```
s = int(''.join(strng[n:]))+1
```

I believe your code essentially works, so I am not going to offer up a completely different solution. I did, however, want to also point out a few other suggestions:

1. You are checking for `strng[n] in ascii_lowercase`. Why not check for `strng[n] not in digits`? This is *not* a big deal, but would allow upper case letters, punctuation, etc. in your input string.
2. You have a statement: `return strng+str(1)`. Why not just make it: `return strng + '1'`? Again, *not* a big deal but just a bit more direct.
3. In the statement `s = int(''.join(strng[n:]))+1`, `strng[n:]` is just a string and so `''.join(strng[n:])` just yields `strng[n:]`. So this statement can be simplified to `s = int(strng[n:])+1`.
4. You do not need to pre-initialize variables `k` and `s` to 0, because they are set later on before they will be first read.